# Driver for Firgelli controller board

Tags: ros, usb, driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to interface a USB controllable motor controller using ROS, I need a c++ driver that I might use. The controller is (http://www.firgelli.com/products.php?id=39).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10974/driver-for-firgelli-controller-board/) by [dhruv](https://answers.ros.org/users/977/dhruv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have had a lot of success in talking to various serial and USB devices using a serial class that I wrote. You can find the serial class files [here](http://ibotics.ucsd.edu/stingray/browser/trunk/os5000/) (in src/ and include/), along with how I use that class to communicate with a digital compass. You would need to find an API/SDK for your motor controller that tells you what commands and responses are available for your device. Then, you would need to write code to initialize your device, send appropriate commands to move the motors and read any responses.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2011-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0